# Cannot cat shift-jis file in mac terminal

Tags: macos, encoding, shift-jis

I have a file that emacs correctly displays on mac. When I cat or less the file in mac terminal I see garbled characters such as "?E?u?@?@?@?@?@?@?@?". Running chardetect indicates SHIFT-JIS.

I tried adding the following to ~./bashrc but still see the same output.

```
export LANG=ja_JP.SHIFT_JIS
export LC_ALL=ja_JP.SHIFT_JIS
```

Under encodings in preferences for terminal, all encodings are checked including the Japanese ones.
Am I missing some other method here for viewing these files? I can see other files with Japanese characters in the mac terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the text encoding at the `Advanced` tab in **profile** preferences to make Terminal use different encoding.
[image: Terminal profile preferences]

Env vars (LANG, LC_ALL) only affect the shell and child processes.

Also note that some characters from Windows cannot be displayed (①,髙,Ⅰ (roman digit) etc).

Comment: For iTerm2, `Preferences` > `Profiles` > `Terminal` > `Character encoding` > `Japanese (Shift JIS)`.